# How do I daily reset pandas time series cumsum?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I import some timeseries data with pd.read_csv and it looks like this:

```
                     price  quantity initiator
time                                          
2016-07-13 16:19:31   6.20      8000         B
2016-07-13 16:19:45   6.19      5176         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     15000         NaN
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2847         S
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     39829         B
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.35      2398         B
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.30      1844         NaN
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.25      9538         S
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.15       459         B
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.25      1082         B
```

I then use the following code to accumulate the 'quantity' column with the following conditions; if 'initiator' = B/S/NaN then the quantity is positive/negative/not counting.

```
instr['multipl'] = np.where(instr.initiator == 'B', 1, -1) * instr.initiator.notnull()
instr['acc_qnty'] = (instr.quantity * instr.multipl).cumsum()
```

I then have a new column with the accumulated quantity. However, I would also like to reset/start over every day. New day, new accumulation.

How can I do that using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.initiator == 'B', 1, -1) * df.initiator.notnull() * df.quantity

df['result'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['new'].cumsum()

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
                     price  quantity initiator  multipl    new  result
2016-07-13 16:19:31   6.20      8000         B        1   8000    8000
2016-07-13 16:19:45   6.19      5176         S       -1  -5176    2824
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     15000       NaN        0      0    2824
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24      2847         S       -1  -2847     -23
2016-07-13 16:25:08   6.24     39829         B        1  39829   39806
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.35      2398         B        1   2398    2398
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.30      1844       NaN        0      0    2398
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.25      9538         S       -1  -9538   -7140
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.15       459         B        1    459   -6681
2016-07-14 09:25:08   6.25      1082         B        1   1082   -5599
```